# Best approach to update page views of millions of rows in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, mongodb, logic

**Scenario**

I have a database of over 2.5 Million Videos and Viewed daily over a million times (total). In my case I am storing all events in NoSQL (mongodb) and then process it to generate a hourly/daily report. I also calculate number of views in total of each object.

**Problem**

These views are stored in MongoDB and are more than 2.5 million (like Mysql), what is the best approach to update MySQL table or in other words how to update all these 2.5 million videos?

Many videos do not get any view, and many get thousands.

**My current approach**

Saves last update time and set the next update time in a separate collection for each video, run the cron, sort them with time, and update them one by one.

Tell me if there is any other/better solution I should go for?

**Elaboration**

Views are counted in mongodb and I need to update mysql table.

Each object has its document with total views and last update time in mongodb db

Cron fetches documents from mongodb w.r.t to time, loops it and update mysql table field of each video.

This way I can also restrict if video views are increased and update only those who get viewed.

P.S I am not sure If i am posting it in the right section, its more related to algorithm and logic building and is figuring out the best approach for almost big data.

Comment: Your question needs more details.  What are you trying to update in MySQL?  Where is the table with the "update" time?  What does "update time" have to do with "number of views"?

Comment: Same as @GordonLinoff , I am unsure of your current strategy and what your looking for. It seems as though you are looking for video analytics but then why are you going about your current method? This is not the method I am sure 90% of us would do, so yeah, this question needs more abut the workings of your sysem.

Comment: Added more info, hope I am clear.

Comment: And yes I am working on video analytics but need views in mysql to ease up data fetch. Sort of YouTube approach

Comment: Ah ok I see now you are attempting to completely recalc the stats for that video once every so often. This is very hard to do and won't scale easily, even with some a processor this might be a troublesome one due to it not needing to be done. Have you looked into things like pre-aggregation of stats: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/ that way you can throw these already calced stats into MySQL and you don't need to worry about processing those 2.5m views, they are just there for detail/unique calculations etc

Comment: @sammaye I have already aggregated views, just need to update mysql table.

Comment: What stops you from updating incrementally when you aggregate in MongoDB? I mean I am just tying to avoid saying "Meh all 2.5m go in"

Comment: Nothing is stopping me, I am asking the best approach. Please tell me if there is any better solution.

Comment: Nah I have done this in a video site I made too where In used sphinx sourced from MySQL, I just shot a quick ping to the MySQL instance, was good. I think any other way and you will have delays or have to writ 2.5m rows all at once